# How to process only the newest message using an out-of-context hook

Tags: delphi, focus, hook

In my application I use a winevent hook to get focus changes system-wide. Because there are no timing problems, I use an out-of-context hook, even if I know that it is slow. If there are multiple events fired quickly on after another, the system queues them and gives them to the hook callback function in the right order.

Now I would like to process only the newest focus change. So if there are already other messages in the queue, I want the callback function to stop and restart with the parameters of the newest message. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a focus change, create an asynchronous notification to yourself, and cancel any previous notification(s) that may still be pending.

You can use `PostMessage()` and `PeekMessage(PM_REMOVE)` for that.  Post a custom message to yourself, removing any previous custom message(s) that are still in the queue.

Or, you can use `TTimer`/`SetTimer()` to (re)start a timer on each focus change, and then process the last change when the timer elapses.

Either way, only the last notification will be processed once the messages slow down.